# How to avoid 2013 error when executing ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a huge table (2.8 GB) and I need to add a column. After I run this query I experience a lost connection error (Error code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query):

```
ALTER TABLE `huge_one` 
ADD COLUMN `extra_column` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `existing_column`;
```

It seems the problem is related to memory shortage though I have these settings in the config file:

```
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

Is that problem really related to innodb_log_file_size setting and is it possible to handle it without increasing innodb_log_file_size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: Check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout